# IdentityServer4 - AuthorizeAttribute doesn't validate the JWT token / Custom user store

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4, identity, asp.net-core-5.0

I have Angular 12 frontend and ASP.NET Core 5 backend. The backend has IdentityServer4 implemented with a custom user store, because it can easily be replaced with an Active Directory one later on.

The problem is that `AuthorizeAttribute` (`[Authorize]`) doesn't work. It just keeps showing 401 unauthorized. I assume something is wrong with `services.AddAuthentication`, because it is responsible for the token's validation.

I also want to be able to make use of the roles `[Authorize(Roles = Role.Administrator,Role.DepartmentAdministrator)]`. I believe if the token starts to work `RoleClaimType = "role"` would make it work, but I cannot be sure until I fix the token validation first.

#### Snippet

```cs
public static class InfrastructureServicesExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddInfrastructureServices(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        ...
        
        services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
        {
            options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
            options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
            options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
            options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;

            options.EmitStaticAudienceClaim = true;
        })
            .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
            .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Configuration.GetIdentityResources())
            .AddInMemoryApiScopes(Configuration.GetApiScopes())
            .AddInMemoryApiResources(Configuration.GetApiResources(configuration))
            .AddInMemoryClients(Configuration.GetClients(configuration))
            .AddCustomUserStore();

        services.AddAuthentication(IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        //.AddJwtBearer(options =>
        //{
        //    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        //    options.SaveToken = true;
        //    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        //    {
        //        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        //        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(configuration["AuthConfiguration:ClientSecret"])),
        //        ValidateIssuer = false,
        //        ValidateAudience = false
        //    };
        //});
            .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, jwtOptions =>
            {
                jwtOptions.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
                jwtOptions.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            },
            referenceOptions =>
            {
                referenceOptions.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";

                referenceOptions.RoleClaimType = "role";

                referenceOptions.ClientId = configuration["AuthConfiguration:ClientId"];
                referenceOptions.ClientSecret = configuration["AuthConfiguration:ClientSecret"];
            });

        return services;
    }
}

[Authorize]
public class RoomsController : ApiControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IList<RoomDto>>> GetRooms()
    {
        var result = await Mediator.Send(new GetRoomsQuery()).ConfigureAwait(false);

        return Ok(result);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<int>> Create(CreateRoomCommand command)
    {
        return await Mediator.Send(command).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    [HttpPut("{id:int}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Update(int id, UpdateRoomCommand command)
    {
        if (id != command.Id)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        await Mediator.Send(command).ConfigureAwait(false);

        return NoContent();
    }

    [HttpDelete("{id:int}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Delete(int id)
    {
        await Mediator.Send(new DeleteRoomCommand { Id = id }).ConfigureAwait(false);

        return NoContent();
    }
}

public static class CustomIdentityServerBuilderExtensions
{
    public static IIdentityServerBuilder AddCustomUserStore(this IIdentityServerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();

        builder
            .AddProfileService<CustomProfileService>()
            .AddResourceOwnerValidator<CustomResourceOwnerPasswordValidator>();

        return builder;
    }
}

public class CustomProfileService : IProfileService
{
    private readonly IUserRepository _userRepository;

    public CustomProfileService(IUserRepository userRepository)
    {
        _userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    public Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
    {
        var sub = context.Subject.GetSubjectId();
        var user = _userRepository.FindById(sub);

        var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new("username", user.Username),
            new("email", user.Email),
            new("role", user.Role.ToDescriptionString())
        };

        context.IssuedClaims = claims;

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task IsActiveAsync(IsActiveContext context)
    {
        var sub = context.Subject.GetSubjectId();
        var user = _userRepository.FindById(sub);

        context.IsActive = user != null;

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}

public class UserRepository : IUserRepository
{
    private readonly List<User> _users = new()
    {
        new User
        {
            Id = "1",
            Username = "admin",
            Password = "123456",
            Email = "admin@uni-ruse.bg",
            Role = Role.Administrator
        },
        new User
        {
            Id = "2",
            Username = "katadmin",
            Password = "123456",
            Email = "katadmin@uni-ruse.bg",
            Role = Role.DepartmentAdministrator
        },
        new User
        {
            Id = "3",
            Username = "user",
            Password = "123456",
            Email = "user@uni-ruse.bg",
            Role = Role.User
        }
    };

    public bool ValidateCredentials(string username, string password)
    {
        var user = FindByUsername(username);
        return user != null && user.Password.Equals(password);
    }

    public User FindById(string id)
    {
        return _users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
    }

    public User FindByUsername(string username)
    {
        return _users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Username.Equals(username, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
    }
}

public class CustomResourceOwnerPasswordValidator : IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator
{
    private readonly IUserRepository _userRepository;

    public CustomResourceOwnerPasswordValidator(IUserRepository userRepository)
    {
        _userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    public Task ValidateAsync(ResourceOwnerPasswordValidationContext context)
    {
        if (_userRepository.ValidateCredentials(context.UserName, context.Password))
        {
            var user = _userRepository.FindByUsername(context.UserName);
            context.Result = new GrantValidationResult(user.Id, OidcConstants.AuthenticationMethods.Password);
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}

public enum Role
{
    [Description("Администратор")]
    Administrator,

    [Description("Катедрен администратор")]
    DepartmentAdministrator,

    [Description("Потребител")]
    User
}

public class User
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public Role Role { get; set; }
}

public static class Configuration
{
    public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> GetIdentityResources() =>
        new List<IdentityResource>
            {
            new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
            new IdentityResources.Profile()
            };

    public static IEnumerable<ApiScope> GetApiScopes() =>
        new List<ApiScope>
        {
            new("assapi", "Academic Schedule API")
        };

    public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> GetApiResources(IConfiguration configuration) =>
        new List<ApiResource>
        {
            new("assapi", "Academic Schedule API")
            {
                ApiSecrets = new List<Secret>
                {
                    new(configuration["AuthConfiguration:ClientSecret"].Sha256())
                },
                Scopes =
                {
                    "assapi"
                }
            }
        };

    public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients(IConfiguration configuration) =>
        new List<Client>
        {
            new()
            {
                ClientName = configuration["AuthConfiguration:ClientName"],
                ClientId = configuration["AuthConfiguration:ClientId"],
                ClientSecrets = { new Secret(configuration["AuthConfiguration:ClientSecret"].Sha256()) },

                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPasswordAndClientCredentials,
                AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Jwt,
                AllowOfflineAccess = true,

                AccessTokenLifetime = 120,
                IdentityTokenLifetime = 120,
                UpdateAccessTokenClaimsOnRefresh = true,
                SlidingRefreshTokenLifetime = 300,
                RefreshTokenExpiration = TokenExpiration.Absolute,
                RefreshTokenUsage = TokenUsage.OneTimeOnly,
                AlwaysSendClientClaims = true,

                AllowedScopes =
                {
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OfflineAccess,
                    "assapi"
                }
            }
        };
}
```

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    if (Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Academic Schedule API V1");
    });

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseIdentityServer();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I forgot that I could see the log when I start it as a console app. It told me that there was a problem with the issuer and in fact it really didn't match the one from the Configuration class. Now they do match and the token works fine.

```cs
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, Roles = "Administrator")]
```

Roles are working too.

```cs
RoleClaimType = "role"
```